# equivalent of R's View for Python's pandas

Tags: python, r, pandas, pycharm

The `View` is a very useful function to allow me to see cross-section of large data frames in R.

Is there any equivalent of R's `View` function for Python's pandas `DataFrame`?

I use `RStudio` for R and `PyCharm` for Python.

Comment: the `.describe()` method and `.head()` or `.tail()` work great. I would suggest getting comfortable with those methods. Once you're dealing with data of more than a few thousand rows, looking at the full frame is not only unhelpful but also a huge burden on your machine...

Comment: nope. these doesn't help. head and tail (in both R and pandas) only give limited view and doesn't help me uncover issues. I'm specifically interested in the corresponding `View` function for pandas. head and tail are fine to check if a code run fine, not a replacement for data visualization.

Comment: I heard you. But I'm telling you to try to move away from the `View` function in `R`.  `View` is not "data visualization" but instead a table showing your data.  But to answer your question, `pandas` doesn't have anything that brings up a new window showing you the full data.

Comment: good to know. makes life harder though. `pandas` is faster than `R` for sure, but I guess I will have to revert to `R` whenever I have to do development (vs. production) work

Comment: @Justin "huge burden on your machine" not for RStudio, whose `View()` function dynamically loads the data in chunks, lets you sort, filter, etc.

Comment: *"pandas is faster than R for sure..."* is utterly wrong: see here https://github.com/Rdatatable/data.table/wiki/Benchmarks-:-Grouping

Answer (score 18, accepted):

A quicker option might be to set the pandas dataframe so it doesn't line wrap by putting this line of code:

```
import pandas
pandas.set_option('expand_frame_repr', False)
```

I'm using Sublime Text 2 and this is how it looks:

**Before putting in option** (Notice how the output wraps the text around)
[image: Before]

**After putting in option** (Notice how the output continues)
[image: After]

Also make sure that 'View' > 'Word Wrap' is not checked.

Additionally, you can print out more or less as you need by using *head(#)* like this:

```
mydf = pandas.DataFrame.from_csv('myfile.csv', header=1)
print mydf.head(20) # Prints first 20 lines
```

Here's some other pandas options:

```
pandas.set_option('display.max_columns', 0) # Display any number of columns
pandas.set_option('display.max_rows', 0) # Display any number of rows
```

Comment: With PyCharm you can use the debugger and use 'Run' > 'Evaluate Expression'.  You can view NumPy's by default and right now it doesn't seem to support DataFrames, but you can evaluate `mydf.as_matrix()` to see the DataFrame contents.

Comment: isn't that only activated during debugging?

Comment: Yeah, unfortunately debugger only.

Answer (score 8):

Spyder within Anaconda (or R Studio for Python as I like to call it) gives you the ability to view and sort entire dataframes the same way you would in R using the variable explorer.

https://www.continuum.io/

[image]

Comment: if you can not see the table properly, try restart the spyder

Answer (score 4):

If you are a regular R user and using python also and you like R studio more then I would recommend you to use R Studio to write python scripts.
You can use the reticulate library for the same.
`reticulate::conda_python()` will take you to the python console and to write a script, just create new python script from the menu.
Next consider the following code written in python:

```
import pandas as pd
df_python = pd.DataFrame({'num_legs': [2, 4, 8, 0],
               'num_wings': [2, 0, 0, 0],
               'num_specimen_seen': [10, 2, 1, 8]},
              index=['falcon', 'dog', 'spider', 'fish'])
```

This will create a pandas dataframe df_python

[image]

Now exit from the python console using `exit` keyword. Now when you will use py$ then you can access python objects. This can let you use this dataframe in R as well and hence you can view the dataframe also using `View(py$df_python)` and you will have the following output.

[image]

Keep Coding!

Answer (score 1):

In ipython (notebook or qtconsole), you can do:

```
from IPython.display import HTML
HTML(myDataFrame.to_html())
```

Doesn't help with pycharm, but it may be worth pursuing.

Comment: must be something about my settings.

Comment: it crashes your notebook =/