# Viewing dataframes in Spyder using a command in its console

Tags: python, r, rstudio, spyder

I have been using R Studio for quite some time, and I find `View()` function very helpful for viewing my datasets.

Is there a similar `View()` counterpart in Spyder?

Comment: [Possible duplicate?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/21834676/equivalent-of-rs-view-for-pythons-pandas)

Comment: Can you please elaborate?

Comment: You can click on the object to view it.

Answer (score 27):

(*Spyder maintainer here*) There's no function similar to `view()` in Spyder. To view the contents of a Dataframe, you need to double-click on it in the Variable Explorer.

Comment: Double click seems not support pandas data frame in my spyder

Comment: hope you can wrap it into a function,it's very useful when the variable explorer has too many variables.